# unetsim: Is there a functionality to move a node from one coordinate to another by passing command from another node?

Tags: unetstack

Is there a way to command one node using another node to move to a specific location, such as a particular coordinate? If so, please share the sample code (if possible).

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an agent that receives a message from another node and just sets its own location based on that. Example code snippet:

```
void processMessage(Message msg) {
  if (msg instanceof DatagramNtf && msg.protocol == MY_PROTOCOL) {
    // extract location x, y from msg based on your PDU encoding
    def node = agentForService Services.NODE_INFO
    node.location = [x, y]
  }
}
```

This method will allow you to implement complex behaviors such as slowly moving the node to the location, in your agent.

As an alternative, if all you need is to instantaneously change the location, you could also consider running a command/script using the remote service on the target node (e.g. 2) to set its own location (e.g. [10,10]):

```
send new RemoteScriptReq(to: 2, scriptName: '@node.location = [10,10]')
```

The `@` prefix causes the `scriptName` to be interpreted as a command, rather than a locally stored script. Do note that this prefix will work in releases up to 1.4, but the behavior will be changed in the upcoming UnetStack release to use a new message `RemoteExecReq`:

```
send new RemoteExecReq(to: 2, command: 'node.location = [10,10]')
```

For the remote service to work, you need the `RemoteControl` agent enabled in the stack on the target node.